# How do I avoid an asp postback when adding code dynamically via asp:Literal?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, postback

I've got a rather simple aspx page that fetches an html filename from a database, finds that file on a network share and adds it to a content area within the page. I've got a select element with an onchange attribute in the html file, but when I change the value of the select element the page is doing a postback, and of course once done the value reverts to it's initial state.

**How can I prevent the server side code from firing when controls in the html have events that need to fire?**

relevant aspx code:

```
<asp:Literal ID="htmlbody" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

<!--Jquery -->
<script src="ClientResources/vendor/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="ClientResources/vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- My javascript -->
<script src="ClientResources/lib/CoordSheet_Shared.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

C# code behind

```
...
using using HtmlAgilityPack;
...

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // In my actual code I get this filename from a database, but that doesn't matter to the problem
        string fileName = "SomeFile.html";
        if (fileName != null)
        {

            string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine("\\\\Network\\Path\\",  fileName);

            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(filepath);

            string bodyhtml = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").WriteContentTo();
            htmlbody.Text = bodyhtml;

        }
    }
```

**EDIT TO SHOW JAVASCRIPT CODE**
The event is an inline onchange attribute

```
<select id="Coordsheet_PageHeight" onchange="Coordsheet_PaperSizeSelected(); Coordsheet_MakeLayoutPrintable();">
    <option value="10" data-numslices="1"></option>
    <option value="7.5" data-numslices="25">8.5" x 11" Landscape</option>
    <option value="10" data-numslices="30">8.5" x 11" Portrait</option>
    <option value="10" data-numslices="30" selected="">11" x 17" Landscape</option>
    <option value="16" data-numslices="30">11" x 17" Portrait</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="10" data-numslices="1">11" Plotter</option>
    <option value="24" data-numslices="1">24" Plotter</option>
    <option value="36" data-numslices="1">36" Plotter"</option>
    <option value="Custom">Custom Height</option>
</select>
```

Here is the javascript code. Essentially it's splitting a large svg element into a series of slices that will word wrap when printed.

```
function Coordsheet_MakeLayoutPrintable(){
    // This function divides the SVGMaster into slices that may be printed
    // The new elements will be placed in the same div as the SVGMaster div

    // This function resizes the layout SVG
    var pageHeight = $('#Coordsheet_CustomPageHeight').val();
    var numSlices = $('#Coordsheet_CustomSliceCount').val();


    // Determine where to put the child divs
    var holderDiv = document.getElementById('SVGSlicesDiv');
    holderDiv.innerHTML = "";

    // Get the attributes saved when the SVGMaster was created
    var attribObj = document.getElementById('SVGAttribObj');
    var width = parseFloat(attribObj.getAttribute('data-canvasWidth'))
    var height = parseFloat(attribObj.getAttribute('data-canvasHeight'))

    // Make a series of containers for the svg element in the result holder div
    var blockWidth = width / numSlices;
    var pageWidth = blockWidth * pageHeight/height;

    for (var i = 0; i < numSlices; i++) {
        x = i * blockWidth;

        var s = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        s.innerHTML = '<use xlink:href="#SVGMaster">';
        s.setAttribute("viewBox", x + " " + 0 + " " + (blockWidth) + " " + (height));
        s.setAttribute("width", blockWidth);
        s.setAttribute("height", height);

        // Viewport size (size visible)
        s.setAttribute("height", pageHeight + "in");
        s.setAttribute("width", pageWidth + "in");
        holderDiv.appendChild(s);
    }

}

function Coordsheet_PaperSizeSelected(){
    // This function is hit when the coordsheet size dropdown value is changed
    var pageHeightSelection = $('#Coordsheet_PageHeight').val();
    var numSlices = $('#Coordsheet_PageHeight option:selected').attr('data-numSlices');

    if (pageHeightSelection == 'Custom'){
        $('#Coordsheet_PaperSizeControlTable').show();

    } else {
        $('#Coordsheet_CustomPageHeight').val(pageHeightSelection);
        $('#Coordsheet_CustomSliceCount').val(numSlices);
        $('#Coordsheet_PaperSizeControlTable').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your Select element?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in SomeFile.html that is being loaded? Does that contain any form elements or javascript?

Comment: There are no form elements in the html, but there are some JavaScript snippets in it. Is there really no way to tell asp pages to run all controls within a div to run client side?